# Open a website after verifying a string (google appscript)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this piece of code that is supposed to open a website after verifying a string. To say that I'm new to coding is an understatement (since I basically don't know a single thing about coding), however, I am trying to learn as I go. Please note that in the provided code, I have fiddled only as far as I can read (even then I don't know if I'm reading the code correctly (you guys will let me know?)). Anyway, when I run it, the code doesn't work. Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
function Search() {

  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  
  var str   = formS.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var values  = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
    
      formS.getDataRange("C10").setValue(row[0])
      formS.getDataRange("C12").setValue(row[1])
      formS.getDataRange("C14").setValue(row[2])
      formS.getDataRange("E10").setValue(row[3])
      formS.getDataRange("E12").setValue(row[4])
      formS.getDataRange("E14").setValue(row[5])

} 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{
showURL('MyApp1','str','MyApp2','str');
showAnchor('MyApp2','str');
}

function showURL(name1,href1,name2,href2){ // for ease of use I give the urls as parameters but you could define these urls in the function as well
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(60).setWidth(200);
  app.setTitle("Show URLs");
  var link1 = app.createAnchor(name1, href1);
  var link2 = app.createAnchor(name2, href2);

  app.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(link1).add(link2));  // add others as needed
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
  }  
  
function xxx(){
  var noFormat = '12345678'
  var formatted = Utilities.formatString("%012d", noFormat);
Logger.log(formatted)
}

function testNew(){
  showAnchor('Ultradox2','str');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
} }}
```

Comment: Where did you find the code?

Comment: Did you get a solution? Could you please provide some feedback?

Comment: To make the question work well, I changed the title according to [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and removed the broken snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The function `Search()` looks more or less ok, so let's assume that it works fine. In this case I think you need just the last function `showAnchor()` to open the dialog window with the link. Something like this:

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;

function Search() {

  var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  
  var str   = formS.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var values  = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];

    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
    
      formS.getDataRange("C10").setValue(row[0])
      formS.getDataRange("C12").setValue(row[1])
      formS.getDataRange("C14").setValue(row[2])
      formS.getDataRange("E10").setValue(row[3])
      formS.getDataRange("E12").setValue(row[4])
      formS.getDataRange("E14").setValue(row[5])
  
      showAnchor('CLICK HERE', 'https://google.com');  // <---- the dialog window fires here

    }
  }
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

But how did you mean to run the function `Search()`? From the Script Editor? Technically it works. You can do it this way, if it suits you.

**Update**

Here is the code for your real spreadsheet:

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get ID from the 'Form' sheet
  var sh_form = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var id = sh_form.getRange('B5').getValue();

  // get the rows 2D array and the header array from the 'Data' sheet
  var sh_data = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var [header, ...rows] = sh_data.getDataRange().getValues();

  // get a list of IDs and a list of URLs from the rows
  var ids = rows.map(x => x[header.indexOf('Response ID')]);
  var urls = rows.map(x => x[header.indexOf('Unique URL')]);

  // find the row with given ID among IDs
  var row = ids.indexOf(id);

  // if the row exists, show the dialog
  if (row > -1) { 
    var url = urls[row];
    showAnchor('CLIK HERE', url);
  }

  // or do something else if nothing found
  else {
    ss.toast('ID not found')
  }

}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

All you need is to assign the 'main' function to the button (arrow) 'continue'

[image]

Comment: @yuri_khristich. Thank you for your response. so I implemented your suggestion, now I'm getting an error:  UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead. I don't understand, because I was under the impression that I was using HtmlService, I don't know what I'm missing pleas help? Again Thank you

Comment: Remove (or comment out) from you code everything but my variant of the script. My snipped has no `UiApp` as you can see. It can't get such error. And make sure that you have just one .gs file in your project.

Comment: Still not winning my good friend... the script runs when remove UiApp but it doesn't give me the desired result. in fact nothing happens... I just get a notification "script running" - "script finished running" but nothing happens

Comment: Most likely the condition `if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {` gets you `false` this why nothing happens. I'm sure, the error is in your data, and/or the way the data is grabbing. Share your sheet and I'll try to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I copied this code, made `Form` and `Data` sheets, change `formS.getDataRange(...).setValue(row[..])` to `formS.getRange(...).setValue(row[..])`. After run there are some values from `Data` to `Form` copied and a modal window with link shown. I think this answer should be accepted.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for helping. Okay so I’ve been fiddling around with the code, and have gotten part of it to work but it is unable to verify the user and thus can’t provide the unique url. Here is a link to a folder with notes and pictures, including the sheet - https://rebrand.ly/c85e7a -. Everything is in view only, please make copies.

Comment: Thank you for real data, it's much easier to figure out what's going on if there is a real spreadsheet. I've updated my answer with the new sample of code.

Comment: @yuri_khristich. Could you please share the spreadsheet, just to make it easier for me. thanks again for the help.

Comment: Five hours with no reaction. Good luck, bud. I'm done

Comment: @yuri_khristich. Thank you for providing help as far as you did. its just pity you could not share the spreadsheet. I still appreciate the help, thanks again.

Comment: @David Lukas. Thanks for the input my friend. much appreciated.